# "nodename nor servname provided" when trying to start a mesos-slave

Tags: ssh, installation, cluster-computing, bigdata, mesos

I was following this simple guide on installing Mesos locally https://mesosphere.com/2014/07/07/installing-mesos-on-your-mac-with-homebrew/

I was able to start a mesos master and was able to see the master's console perfectly fine at localhost:5050. However when I tried to start a new slave using sudo /usr/local/sbin/mesos-slave --master=127.0.0.1:5050 , it gave me

WARNING: Logging before InitGoogleLogging() is written to STDERR
F0328 16:14:45.329051 2041414416 process.cpp:889] nodename nor servname provided, or not known
*** Check failure stack trace: ***

Any help will be appreciated, thanks

Comment: Could you please show us which IP the master has bound to? Should look somewhat like this: `I0329 16:22:33.670699 302264320 master.cpp:359] Master 20150329-162233-347252928-5050-20706 (hostname.domain.name) started on IP:PORT`. Is your hostname properly configured? What does this result to: `ping $(hostname -f)`?

Answer (score 5):

This can also happen if you working on a Framework and attempting to connect to a Mesos Master.  Mesos is attempting to resolve your computer's name via DNS and isn't finding an entry. This can happen if you've changed your Mac's hostname post setup ( as I did, and had this same error ).

To fix, run `hostname -f`, that will will give you the value of what OS/X thinks it's name is.  Then simply ensure you've got `127.0.0.1 VALUE_OF_HOSTNAME_-F` in your `/etc/hosts` file.

Comment: This worked for me for launching Spark on a locale Mesos cluster. However, it still remains the annoying warning:


`**************************************************
Master bound to loopback interface! Cannot communicate with remote schedulers or slaves. You might want to set '--ip' flag to a routable IP address.
**************************************************`
Of course, the --ip flag is set...
Thanks a lot

Comment: The solution was to have `127.0.0.1 VALUE_OF_HOSTNAME` in `/etc/hosts`, no need for `-F`.